# Stop Monk from adding _id to docs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

Is there a way to stop monk from generating and adding _id to docs ?
Or is there a driver for MongoDb in Node.js that doesn't auto add _id ?

Comment: I guess _id is needed in every doc. If you don't want auto generated _id then you have to add a custom one. But every doc should have _id in mongo.

Comment: You mean to manually add _id when inserting ?

Comment: Yes. you can add your own _id and insert it when inserting doc. Just make sure _id is unique across all docs in a collection. Its should be like what primary key is in RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_id is needed in every doc. If you don't want auto generated _id then you have to add a custom one. But every doc should have _id in mongo.

You can add your own _id and insert it when inserting doc. Just make sure _id is unique across all docs in a collection. It should be what primary key is in RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.createCollection("noautoid", { autoIndexId: false });
```

This will create a collection without _id but the option is deprecated and will be removed in next versions.